# use slugs instead of id

Tags: php, laravel

I develop a site with laravel 5.8 and I would like to use slugs rather than id. tote knowing that I have two table services and type-services. the service key is foreign in the service-type table.

I retrieve and display the services by the type of service. but on my url the type id is displayed.

I have this error

Missing required parameters for [Route: service] [URI: service/{slug}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\elbi\resources\views\layouts\partial\nav.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\elbi\resources\views\layouts\partial\nav.blade.php)

the tables:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('type_services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id');
            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Models

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model
{
    public function typeservice()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Typeservice');
    }


}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TypeService extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
    }
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

display controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        $abouts = About::all();
        $services = Service::with('typeservice')->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
        $typeservices =TypeService::all();
        $makings = Making::all();
        $realisations = Realisation::all();
        $addresses = Address::all();
        return view('index',compact('contacts','services','abouts','typeservices','makings','realisations','addresses'));
    }

 public function service(Service $service)
    {
        $abouts = About::all();
        $services = Service::with(['typeservice'=> function($query){
            $query->where('name');
        }])->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
        $typeservices =$service ->typeservice()->where('service', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name');
        })->paginate(5);;
        $makings = Making::all();
        $realisations = Realisation::all();
        return view('service.service',compact('services','abouts','typeservices','makings','realisations'));
    }
```

Route

```
/*controller front */
Route::get('/','FrontController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/contact','FrontController@send')->name('send');
Route::post('/contact','ContactController@sendMessage');
Route::get('/about','FrontController@about')->name('about');
Route::get('/service/{slug}', 'FrontController@service')->name('service');
```

view

```
   <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach($services as $service)
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{route('service',$service->id)}}">{{$service->name}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
```

I would like to use slug and not id

Answer (score 3):

You could try giving [Spatie's Laravel-Sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) package a go.

```php
$service = new Service();
$service->name = 'This is a service';
$service->save();

echo $service->slug; // ouputs "this-is-a-service"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by storing `slug` in the database and modify your queries in the controller accordingly,
Slug can be set before saving the model as below:

```php
$slug = \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($service->name);
$service->slug = $slug;
```

you can place this logic manually before calling `save` method or use [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) - specifically `saving` event .

Comment: You answer is incomplete/wrong. `\Str::slug` results in error `Class 'Str' not found`.

Comment: I updated the namespace of Str class, it is one of laravel  helpers (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug)

Comment: I'd just like to add that `\Str::slug()` should work without defining its namespace or importing it, if it is correctly aliased in `config/app.php`. You may still need to import `Str`. eg. `use Str;`.